# How to separate an element in list ?(Python)

Tags: python

#### how to separate without space or comma ?

From :
`n = int(input(1234567890121))`

Result:
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,1]`

Answer (score 0):

Well you could loop though the string of that int and then append them to a new list like this:

```
output = []

for i in str(1234567890121):
    output.append(int(i))

print(output)
```

gives:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

##### working with string

Assuming you meant `n = int(input('input a number'))` and typed `1234567890121`

The easiest would be **not** to convert first to integer, but split as list and perform the conversion **after**

```
n = '1234567890121'
list(map(int, list(n)))
```

##### working with integer

If you want to split the integer, you can serially divide by 10:

```
n = 1234567890121
out = []
while n>0:
    n,r = divmod(n,10)
    out.append(r)
out = out[::-1]
```

output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 1]`